# SAPUI5 - Basic info - how to manage UI elements in view.js?

Tags: sapui5

experts,

These are two very basic connected questions.

I'm studying SAPUI5 and I cannot find means to position my UI elements on the screen.
In my view.js file I create, let's say, a button, a datepicker and a text field.
If I do something like:

```
aControls=[];
<Define the button - oButton>
aControls.push(oButton);
<Define the datepicker - oDatePicker>
aControls.push(oDatePicker);
<Define the text field - oText>
aControls.push(oText);
return aControls;
```

then I get all three elements positioned in a row one right after another.
I cannot use css, because I pass all those objects in one array and all of them are placed into a common div on index.html.

How do I position these? A link to any good tutorial/examples is very welcome.

Also, how do I refresh UI elements?
For example, I have situation, when on button press I make a call to the server, get response and put it into a  using something like:

```
response.placeAt('some-id');
```

The button is created in the view.js and the call is processed in controller.js.
The response is added every time I press the button and I have no idea how to replace the old response with the new one.

A good link is very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest having a look at the SAPUI5 SDK documentation, there are numerous examples using layouts and the use of models, which answer both your questions respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of layout controls of SAPUI5 you can use: [Grid](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/layout/demokit/Grid.html), [HorizontalLayout](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/layout/demokit/HorizontalLayout.html), [VerticalLayout](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/layout/demokit/VerticalLayout.html), [MatrixLayout](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/MatrixLayout.html),etc. You can check the examples and see how you need to layout your views.

You are currently doing UI5 [JS view](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.JSView.html) which implements `createContent` method to define views, this is one approach. Another common approach is to use XML views, it is declarative and more straightforward, also needs less code. See this [simple example](http://jsbin.com/tabebimococi/3/edit) in JSBin  of defining XML view and controller to refresh UI.

SAP UI5 is all about Model(**JSONModel/ODataModel**)-View(**JSView/XMLView**)-Controller. You are highly recommend to read this [MVC example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/4dfd24d8de314254987e611a156bdea6.html), though it is based on SAP UI5 mobile, the content is relevant to SAP UI5 desktop as well.

Hope you will get some hints.

Comment: Thanks, I've already read about layouts. That's what I was looking for. Now, I need to read and understand that mvc idea and how I works...